# Laravel10で cron を実行すると log のオーナーが root になってしまう

Tags: docker, laravel, cron

local環境で cron で定期実行するように作成しました。それ自体は問題なく動作しています。
そして、デバッグ用に随所でログを出力しています。 `log::debug()`

ログファイルは管理しやすいように日毎に出力しています。

```php
// .env
LOG_CHANNEL=daily
```

ここで問題になるのが、**新規ログファイルをcron実行時に作成されるとオーナーが root** になり、その後に**通常アクセスによるログを出力しようとすると `サーバー500エラー`** になります。

最初、サーバーエラーが発生するのにログが残っていない、という状態に混乱しました。
ログが書き込めないから、ログが残らない。理由がわかると納得です。

### cron を実行してる環境

1. `sail artisan sail:publish` にてDockerfileフォルダと関連ファイル作成
2. Dockerfileフォルダ内のphpバージョンにある supervisord.conf にcron を追加

```
[program:cron]
command=/usr/sbin/cron -f -l 8
autostart=true
stdout_logfile=/var/log/cron.out.log
stderr_logfile=/var/log/cron.err.log
```

3. `scheduler` ファイルを作成して定期実行の命令を記入

```
* * * * * root cd /var/www/html && php artisan schedule:run >> /dev/null 2>&1
```

4. Dockerfileを開いて RUN に `cron` という文字を追加

```
RUN apt-get update \　
    && apt-get install -y cron 以下略
```

5. 同じDockerfileの COPYの前に cron の RUN を追加

```
COPY scheduler /etc/cron.d/scheduler
RUN chmod 0644 /etc/cron.d/scheduler \
    && crontab /etc/cron.d/scheduler
```

### cron の実行者を変更をやってみましたが…

新しいファイルのオーナーが root になってしまう問題が発生したので、cron 実行者を変更するようにしてみました。

Dockerfileのcron実行部分に USER を指定しました。

```
// docker/8.2/Dockerfile
USER my_name  // ←←←←←←←←←← これを追加
COPY scheduler /etc/cron.d/scheduler
RUN chmod 0644 /etc/cron.d/scheduler \
    && crontab /etc/cron.d/scheduler
```

しかし、この設定をしても root でファイルが作成されます。

毎日、オーナー変更のコマンドを実行しなければなりません。

```
sudo chown my_name:my_name laravel-*.log
```

この状況を改善する方法はあるでしょうか？
よろしくお願いします。

**追記 2023-06-25 0:47 **
次の施策も試しみました。
いずれもNG。rootで作成されてしまい目的を達成できていません。

1. Dockerfile COPYの前に `USER my_name` を追加
2. Dcokerfile `RUN useradd -ms /bin/bash --no-user-group -g $WWWGROUP -u 1337 my_name` を追加
3. Dockerfile `RUN chmod 0644 /etc/cron.d/scheduler \(改行)&& crontab -u my_name /etc/cron.d/scheduler` に変更
4. `* * * * * root /bin/su my_name -c "cd /var/www/html && php artisan schedule:run >> /dev/null 2>&1"` に変更
5. さらに後ろに `&& chown my_name:my_name /home/my_name/my_project/storage/logs/*.log"` を追加
6. start-container に `if [ "$(id -u)" = '0' ]; then（改行）exec su - imamura "$0" "$@"（改行）fi` を追加

Answer (score 0):

特定のユーザーで実行するには `/etc/crontab` ではなく `/var/spool/cron/[user]` で設定行うとよいはず
<del>(設定内容は同様に)</del>

あるいは以下のような記述方法も考えられます (コマンドの指定部分)

```
/bin/su user -c "command"
```

---

##### 記述の方法

特定のユーザーでの (通常の) CRON ファイルの記述では
ユーザー名フィールドは**なく**, 日時などの 5項目の後にコマンド

システム CRON ファイルの場合の記述は
**ユーザー名フィールドがあり**, 続いてコマンド

なので `root` と指定している部分を変更するとよいかも

また `/var/spool/cron/[user]` の(通常の) CRON ファイルでは
該当するユーザーで, 以下のようにして編集するとよいでしょう

```bash
$ crontab -e

$ crontab -l   # 内容確認
```

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます。schedulerファイルに　/bin/su user -c "command"　を追加してみましたが、うまくいきませんでした。/var/spool/cron/[user] はdocker外管理になりそうで、なんとかdocker内で処理を収めたいと思っています。